# Why are the values being fread from inptr into an array different than the values given by fgetc(inptr)?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, gdb

I'm trying to iterate over a .raw file looking for the 4 bytes that indicate a jpeg is starting (0xffd8ffe0 or 0xffd8ffe1):

```
int junk = fgetc(inptr);
while (junk != 0xff)
    if (junk == EOF)
    {
        printf("Reached end of file.\n");
        printf("2\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        junk = fgetc(inptr);
    }
```

Once I find 0xff, I fseek(inptr, -1, SEEK_CUR), and then:

```
while (feof(inptr) == 0)
{
    // declared write file outptr

    // write header
    char header[4];
    do
    {
        fread(&header, sizeof(char), 4, inptr);
        if (header[1-4] are 0xffd8ffe0 or 0xffd8ffe1)
            fwrite(&header, 1, 4, outptr);
    } while (header[1-4] are not 0xffd8ffe0 or 0xffd8ffe1);
```

If I'm in GDB and I print fgetc(inptr) 4 times before the while loop begins, sure enough i get 0xffd8ffe0. If I let the do-while loop fwrite to header and then print header in gdb, I get crazy junk values, and the do-while becomes an infinite loop. I have no idea what's happening. Thanks.

Comment: what kind of syntax is 'header[1-4] are not 0xffd8ffe0 or 0xffd8ffe1'? header[1-4] is equivalent to header[-3].

Comment: I think what Peter was trying to say is that you need to show your actual code, not pseudo code, and you need to show it _all_ at once.  Then you should read:  http://commandcenter.blogspot.ca/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: yes, thanks; but not "all", instead (http://sscce.org/) all that matters, and is compilable and produces the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might fail to find the JPEG header in the RAW file even if it's there, if there's a 0xff in the raw part before the header. For instance if the file contains:

```
0x00 0xff 0x00 0x00 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0 <JPEG data>
```

your code won't locate the header.

Instead you should read the file byte by byte (remembering the last three read bytes) and compare those bytes to the constant(s) of the JPEG header.

Comment: Yeah - the .raw file never changes, and I dove in to make sure there were no 0xff's before the first header, understanding that this technique doesn't work in the general case. And sorry for the bad post style with the pseudo-code - I'm going to start from scratch and I suspect I'll be back soon. Thanks.